# Return only _source from a search

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Is it possible to only retrieve the _source document(s) when I execute a search query with the (official) nodejs-elasticsearch library? According to the documentation, there seems to be a way, sort of:

> Use the /{index}/{type}/{id}/_source endpoint to get just the _source field of the document, without any additional content around it. For example:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/1/_source'
```

And the corresponding API call in the nodejs library is:

```
client.getSource([params, [callback]])
```

However, this method only seems to be able to retrieve documents on an ID basis. I need to issue a full search body (with filters and query_strings and whatnot), which this method doesn't support.

I'm running ES 1.4

Answer (score 1):

You can use `"fields"` for this. See a simplified example below. Go ahead and customize your query as per your requirement:

```
{
    "fields": [
        "_source"
    ], 
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
```

The value of fields `_index`, `_type`, `_id` and `_score` will always be present in the response of [Search API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_the_search_api.html).

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. The result I get back still contain stuff around the _source - { "_index": "...", "_type": "...", "_id": "...", "_score": "...", ... }. To clarify, I only want the _source part of the document returned.

Comment: I don't think you can get rid of `_index`, `_type`, `_id` and `_score` fields in the response of Search API. Updating answer.